# Splitting an electricity bill

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the fairest way to split an electricity bill that amounts to 201.44. This is for an 8 week period. Party A(1 Person) stayed for 6 weeks and party B(6 people) stayed for 2 weeks.

Comment: depends on the electricity usage of each individual for the time period they were there if you assume everyone uses the same amount of electricity for a given time period then party $B$ spent an equivalent of $12$ weeks and $A$ spent an equivalent of $6$ weeks so $A$ should pay $(6/18)201.44$ and $B$ should split the rest equally

Comment: I suggest to assume every equal length period consumes the same amount of electricity. We know there are a lot of electric facilities consume the same amount of electricity regardless of the number of tenancy. For example, fridge, tv, heater, etc. More people just means more usage on the light bulbs in their own rooms, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Any split is going to be based on assumptions that may or may not actually be true. The most straightforward approach is to assume that each person used the same amount of electricity per week. On that basis Party $A$ used $6$ person-weeks of electricity, and Party $B$ used $6\cdot2=12$ person-weeks of electricity. Between them the two parties used $6+12=18$ person-weeks, so Party $A$ used $\frac6{18}=\frac13$ of the total and therefore owed

$$\frac13\cdot\$201.44=\$67.15\;.$$

(I’ve rounded that to the nearest cent.) Party $B$ owes the remaining $\$134.29$ and will presumably split this $6$ ways.